# Pressed Buttons are permanently low and one of them is not working

Tags: programming, button, wires

I am a beginner to Arduino, and I'm having a problem in a project that I am currently working on.

I was just beginning to write the code, after preparing the components and the wiring, and suddenly two of my buttons never stopped outputting, despite my instructions to only output when the buttons are low, and the other one doesn't do anything at all.

I am using three buttons, one of them is a interruptor switch.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 3    // input pin Neopixel is attached to
#define NUMPIXELS 28 // number of neopixels in strip

#define TRAVAO 8
#define PISCA 13
#define QUATRO_PISCAS 11

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int redColor = 0;
int greenColor = 0;
int blueColor = 0;

void setup() {
  pixels.begin();
  
  pinMode(TRAVAO, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PISCA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(QUATRO_PISCAS, INPUT_PULLUP);
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(TRAVAO) == LOW) {
    Serial.print("bbb");
  }
  
  if(digitalRead(PISCA) ==  LOW) {
    Serial.print("ccc");
  }
  
  if(digitalRead(QUATRO_PISCAS) ==  LOW) {
    Serial.print("ddd");
  }
  
  delay(1);
}
```

Here is my arduino:

[image]

Comment: I count 42 "pixels" and the code says `#define NUMPIXELS 28` So, I'm wondering how accurate the diagram is to the project. Are there actually 42? Is it really an UNO? etc.

Comment: What happens if you use only the four-LED strip?

Comment: @timemage only 28 are currently wired and being used. The six interior pixels of each circle are not being used.

Comment: @timemage nothing changes.

Comment: `buttons never stopped outputting, despite my instructions to only output when the buttons are low` ... maybe the buttons are always low

Comment: @jsotola could you please clarify?

Comment: maybe the input pins on the arduino are pulled low when the buttons are not pressed ... did you disconnect the wires to the arduino pins to confirm that the program stops printing to serial?

Comment: Make sure your buttons are oriented correctly, not turned 90°.

Comment: An in focus well lit picture of your actual wiring may help.

Comment: i think the slider PISCA not need INPUT_PULLUP
`pinMode(PISCA, INPUT_PULLUP);`
just `pinMode(PISCA, INPUT_PULLUP);`

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
#define TRAVAO 8
```

As you can see from your wiring diagram, nothing is connected to pin 8.